# macOS Rectangle.app equivalent window mover/resizer/snapper on Windows

Tags: windows-10, window-manager

**EDIT:** this problem bothered me to the extent that I coded up my own solution to it and I have been using it. https://github.com/ahmetb/RectangleWin

---

I switched to Windows 10 and I sorely miss the macOS [Rectangle.app](https://rectangleapp.com/) which lets the users to:

- snap windows to left/right/top/bottom half/one-thirds/two-thirds
- center them on the screen
- stretch them to screen

and most importantly it let you assign shortcut keys for those. It was a simple app and it did everything I wanted. Screenshot below from Rectangle.app's repository.

I'm looking at Windows 10 native keys, the PowerToys extensions (FancyZones) and they're falling short of these features.

[image: what a slick app!]

Any recommendations?

Comment: Windows 10 would be my recommendation. Try it. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/snap-your-windows-885a9b1e-a983-a3b1-16cd-c531795e6241.

Comment: @user1644677 that does 1/10th of what I need though.

Comment: Try this then https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/

Comment: @user1644677 I did, and it is listed in my question.

Comment: There is also key remapper.

Comment: You can manipulate windows using utilities like this. https://winsourcecode.blogspot.com/p/test.html. You can use a shortcut to programs and add command line parameters. Shortcuts can have hotkeys assigned to them. Else see AutoHotkey - https://www.autohotkey.com.

Answer (score 0):

So not 100% sure what you're looking for (also 2.5 years later) but when I'm on MacOS the shortcuts I use the most are the half screen and third screen shortcuts.

On Windows 11 that's:
<kbd>Win</kbd> + “Left Arrow” for left half
<kbd>Win</kbd> + “Right Arrow” for right half
<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + “Left or Right Arrow” and it will cycle through the 1/3 sized windows.

Not all the stuff Rectangle has, but the highlights.

Comment: I ended up developing https://github.com/ahmetb/RectangleWin to solve this lol